# how can we prevent special tag inserted into textbox ? in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is there any property or any function is giving which is prevent above issue..

i made a one register form.. and my friend inserted  tag into username.. and it will raise a error at server side.. i tried to prevent it. with validation but.. it cant..

i did it.. check out this line..

```
txt_countryname.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txt_countryname.Text);
```

but its not working ... – Sikender 0 secs ago  [delete this comment]

help me...

Comment: ... please give more info. what is the tag, what validation have you tried?

Comment: ok.. table's tag .. like <tr> <td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good reason for this behavior - to avoid [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

It *can* be disabled by adding this to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>  
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Read through [this article](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/) to find out why disabling request validation is a bad idea.

As CodeMonkey noted, you can also do this on a single page basis in the @page directive:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Which would be a better approach, by not exposing **all** of your pages to xss.

Comment: tell .. me if i dont false it this property.. then error will raised every time.. ok.. so..is it ok!!!! or i should put this property false.. can you tell me...

Comment: Most importantly, if request validation is turned off, it's a good idea to make sure you do your own validation to limit security risks.

Comment: I will vote against this approach because it disables validation on *all* pages, as opposed to my suggestion where you want to only disable validation for single pages.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - added your refrain. Reduce the attack surface by only disabling a single page.

Comment: Request Validation is worthless. It won't protect you from all possible attacks if you're vulnerable, and it will stop people using perfectly valid strings which look like tags when you're *not* vulnerable. Turn it off, get rid of it, burn it, find the programmers responsible and prosecute them for Criminally Bad Idea.

Answer (score 2):

you also can use asp:RegularExpressionValidator
Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Text="Error" ErrorMessage="some error message" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,15}$" SetFocusOnError="True" ControlToValidate="txt_username">
```

Comment: this term called scripting injection .. i dont. know. but we can not solved by using.. validators.. thanks.. but.. you should read oded's link article. ok..thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You will want to, for that page to disable Script-validation. The reason why you are getting that error is because ASP.NET by default validates incoming posts.

[Read more about it](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/)

Answer (score 1):

Server.HtmlEncode

Comment: i did it.. check out this line.. txt_countryname.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txt_countryname.Text); but its not working ...

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx).

Comment: i did it.. check out this line..

txt_countryname.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txt_countryname.Text);

but its not working ...